# android application working but crash after work done

Tags: java, android, crash

my app is about turning phone on ringer mode via sms received but it crashes after its work is completed showing "Unfortunately, your app has stopped responding..". Here is my manifest and receiver.java file

My manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Info" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Help" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Next"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_next" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Next" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.hide.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED"/>

            </intent-filter>

            </receiver>
</application>
```

MYReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

LocationManager lm;   
LocationListener locationListener;   
String sender;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SmsMessage[] sms = null;

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

    String str = " SMS From  ";
    if (b != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");

        sms = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {

            sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            if (i == 0) {
                sender +=  sms[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ":"+sms[i].getMessageBody().toString();
 if (sms[i].getMessageBody().equals("Ring")) {
                    AudioManager am =      (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int maxVolume = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); 
                    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL); 
                    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
}
        }
    }
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Receiving", str);
    }

}
}
```

Further more caused in log is showing NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION(), but i didn't get there is no code that throws exception.
But it is working fine as well it shows unfortunate message whenever i receive message on other app also.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: If it stops working, and crashes, there is a stacktrace.

Comment: Download **CatLog** from **Google Play** if you can't get any stacktrace. Use this app to show stacktraces against your application.

Comment: You are talking about LogCat?? if so then it shows this error.. `05-26 23:33:28.959: E/AndroidRuntime(1752): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Do you want me to post whole LogCat?

Comment: @Disguise yes that will have a more detailed information about crash

Comment: @Disguise Can't see it. Have you saved your edit?

Comment: Sorry i actually deleted it as it was showing other error that i can't seem to understand. I will try again as that error occur whenever other messages arrived or automatically.@Nitish

Comment: My problem is solved by try and catch but i still not get it when i individually run my modules of app it doesn't need any try-catch statement